# How to change Java heap size for Tomcat 9 installed as Windows Service from command line?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, windows-7-x64

I have Tomcat 9 installed as service on Windows 7 64 bit. I want to:

1. see what heap size is currently configured and active
2. update the service configuration persistently to use a different heap size
3. verify that Tomcat is actually using the new heap size.
4. do all that from the command line.

For 1 and 3: I naively tried to use jconsole, but I don't find the process there because Tomcat is running as Local System Service. While I found out how to run jconsole as Local System Account, it seems that JMX is deactivated when Tomcat is installed as service.

So finding out the currently used memory sizes by JMX seems to be at least very complicated (possibly enabling JMX remote, which should be over TLS...).

For 2: I suppose [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Updating_services) is the corresponding place of Tomcat's documentation, which reads:

```
 To update the service parameters, you need to use the //US// parameter.

 Update the service named 'Tomcat9'
 C:\> tomcat9 //US//Tomcat9 --Description="Apache Tomcat Server - http://tomcat.apache.org/ " ^
      --Startup=auto --Classpath=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar
```

But I don't understand that text sufficiently to apply it to my problem. Especially, I don't want to change other parameters (like description, startup etc.).

As far as I understand, when run as a service, configuration is stored in the Windows registry, so the usual configuration in tomcat/conf does not or at least does only partly apply.

Please note that this question is not about installing Tomcat, but about modifying an existing installation. Also I am not interested in some hacky way to get the desired result (somehow), but in the best practice to do that; and it would be perfect to have links to reference documentation for that.

Comment: Have you found a legitimate answer to this yet?

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I don't use Tomcat any more ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Given the documentation that you link to

> --JvmMx
>
> Maximum memory pool size in MB. (Not used in exe mode.)

should help to **control** the heap size.

For fetching the current values, tools such as [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop) might be easiest answer.

Comment: Of course it is a JVM parameter, but the configuration of that parameter belongs to the configuration of the Tomcat9 windows service. And as I already said in the question, it seems the usual batch files are not (or at least differently) used. If you read the section above the one I cited, you'll see that the initial configuration is not done by modifying batch files neither.

Comment: Any feedback on the tool I linked you to?

Comment: Probably it will suffer from the access problems described. From its Github page: "monitor all accessible, running jvms on a machine". (accesible!). I'll try https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/monitoring-java-processes-running-as-a-windows-service first. But I have no more time for that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 and 3 there is `jmap`. You just need to know the process Id of the tomcat instance running.

```
jmap -heap 7082
```

Here is the output from a running jvm I have right now(the relevant lines):

```
Heap Configuration:
MinHeapFreeRatio    = 0
MaxHeapFreeRatio    = 100
MaxHeapSize         = 1073741824 (1024.0MB) // that is -Xmx flag

.... 

NewSize             = 357564416 (341.0MB) // 1
MaxNewSize          = 357564416 (341.0MB)
OldSize             = 716177408 (683.0MB) // 2

1 + 2 = -Xms flag
```

Unfortunately I can't answer 2, since I've never started tomcat on windows - as a service (I hardly know what that means for windows). But assuming this is a process that is started by windows as a script...

Shouldn't : `tomcat9 -Xms512M -Xmx2G...` work? Again, just a hint, not sure. The last thing to notice is that the heap can be changed only at start-up of the jvm, you can't do that at runtime while tomcat is running obviously (just in case...).

Comment: Using jmap I get: 
Attaching to core 4908 from executable heap, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: Windbg Error: OpenDumpFile failed!

Comment: Probably same reason as described above for jconsole.